# How to trigger a set number of ADC conversions with DMA using a hardware timer?

Tags: timer, stm32, dma, adc, stm32f7

I'm working on STM32F767 with STM32CubeIDE using HAL (I don't have time to fully learn bare metal, I'm doing it in my spare time). I have TIM2 set up as a PWM on both CH1 and CH2 with a period of 200us and a duty cycle of 25% for CH1 and approx. 30% for CH2. I also have ADC1 configured at 1.8 Msps. What I want is, on the rising edge of PWM CH2 for ADC to trigger, DMA to read 50 samples (or whatever buffer size I eventually decide on. Right now it's 50) and then for the ADC/DMA to wait until the next rising edge of PWM CH2 to trigger the ADC/DMA for another 50 samples. Simply put, I want the ADC buffer of size 50 to be filled every time PWM CH2 rises. Now, I've already achieved this with interrupts and polling but I want to leave the CPU out of it as much as possible. I want this process to have little overhead on the CPU as possible.

The problem: Once the first rising edge of the PWM CH2 activates the ADC just after board reset, it just runs forever converting the signal and the DMA updates the buffer. I want the PWM to constantly trigger the ADC or the DMA not to just trigger the ADC once and then run forever.

Main:

```html
volatile uint16_t ADC_Val[50];// = {0};
volatile uint16_t ADC_Total[250] = {0};

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, ADC_Val, sizeof(ADC_Val));
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

set up and conversion complete callback where i toggle the GPIO for reference:

```html
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T2_CC2;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 20000;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 5000;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM2;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 6000;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PB0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD8 PD9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

    GPIOA->ODR ^= (1 << 4);
    ADC_flag ++;
    //ADC1->SR &= ~(1 << 0x4);
    asm("NOP");

}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}
```

Interrupt Handlers for completeness:

```html
void ADC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_ADC_IRQHandler(&hadc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles TIM2 global interrupt.
  */
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 stream0 global interrupt.
  */
void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_adc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */

  DMA_flag ++;
 // memcpy(ADC_Total + conversion_flag, ADC_Val, sizeof(ADC_Total));
  
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */
}
```

I have set up a GPIO to toggle every time a conversion is made. TIM2 CH1 is yellow, TIM2 CH2 is blue and the adc complete GPIO toggle is purple. As you can see here, on the first ever rising edge of PWM CH2 the GPIO toggles due to the ADC completing its conversion. This perfect and I want this to repeat every rising edge. However, in the second image it doesn't toggle after the exact same time ever again. It is just constantly running the ADC and toggling without respect to the timer.
[image]

[image]

I'm convinced that I'm 90% there and all i need to do is clear a bit in a register somewhere ready for the next timer trigger but the reference manual is not clear AT ALL so I've resulted to trial and error. Any help or ideas would be great. There doesn't seem to be any control over this function in ther ADC_SR or ADC_CR1/CR2 registers.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is rather old topic.
Nevertheless, if you want ADC conversions to be started each time on specific trigger event you should not use continuous mode. In other words, change:

```
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
```

to

```
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is stop the DMA after your 50 conversions are finished.
[image: Heres the API]
To do this you can use the interrupt the ADC/DMA throws when the attached buffer is full.
[image: Interrupt API]